# SqlAlchemy relationship selecting columns

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, relationship, fastapi

I am trying to find a way to select columns with an sqlalchemy relationships:

I have this two tables:

```
class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'parent'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    label = Column(String)
    children = relationship("Child", back_populates="parent")

class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'child'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('public.parent.id'))
    parent = relationship("Parent", back_populates="children")
```

when i use

```
db.query( models.Parent).first()
```

i get the parent object with the list of Children as i was expecting, but what i would like to do is to select only few columns like that:

```
db.query( models.Parent.id, models.Parent.children)
```

in this case it doesn't work an i get the following error:

Could not locate column in row for column Children

Answer (score 2):

You can use options with `load_only()` function.

```
stmt = select(Parent)

results = await db.execute(
    stmt
    .options(load_only(Parent.id))
    .options(selectinload(Parent.children))
)
```

*If you want picking some columns, just attach `load_only()` like this.

```
.options(selectinload(Parent.children).load_only(Child.id, Child.name))
```

Yes, I tested execute() but, query() will work.

```
session.query(User).options(load_only(User.name, User.fullname))
```

**see also:**
https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/loading_columns.html#sqlalchemy.orm.load_only